# How do I get a clearer axis title

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

I have this example

```
library(MASS)
x = rnorm(50,0,0.00001)
y = rnorm(50,0,.000005)
den2d = kde2d(x,y)

filled.contour(x = den2d$x, y=den2d$y, z=den2d$z, color = terrain.colors, 
               plot.title = title(main = "",
                                  xlab = "SD's of model 1", ylab = "SD's of model 2", cex.lab=0.8),
               plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(-2e-05, 2e-05, by = 1e-05))
                 axis(2, seq(-5e-06, 1.5e-05, by = 5e-06))  },
               key.title = title(main = "Density"),
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(0, 3e+09, by = 5e+08)))
```

which produces something like this

https://gyazo.com/17675f1f31cb738ee86cf77546a811bf

as you can see on the y-axis the title is covered by the values. I was wondering is there a way round this? I want my axis titles to be as large as possible in R as when I put the plots in my report the size of the axis text goes really small so need to compensate by making it larger in R

Answer (score 1):

You could include las=3 to turn the y-axis labels parallel to the axis.

```
filled.contour(x = den2d$x, y=den2d$y, z=den2d$z, color = terrain.colors, 
           plot.title = title(main = "",
                              xlab = "SD's of model 1", ylab = "SD's of model 2", cex.lab=0.8),
           plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(-2e-05, 2e-05, by = 1e-05))
             axis(2, seq(-5e-06, 1.5e-05, by = 5e-06))  },
           key.title = title(main = "Density"),
           key.axes = axis(4, seq(0, 3e+09, by = 5e+08)), 
           las=3)
```